# King David vs King Shaul - did King Shaul do anything wrong?

Tags: halacha, king-david, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, politics-government, king-saul

When Shaul would scold his enemies e.g. the Plishtim, he would shout at them for “defying Israel” (as his men did in Shmuel 1:17:25), but David would shout at them for "defying God" (ibid 26).

I heard this in the name of Rav Kook.

---

Is there any discussion (especially in some sort of *halachic* sense) or criticism of Shaul for acting inappropriately by not mentioning Hashem? Other than Rav Kook

Comment: וכל איביך מהרה יכרתו vs וכל אויבי עמך מהרה יכרתו

Comment: @Rabbi_Kaii where do you see that Shaul would shout at them for "defying Israel" - as you write, that was his men?

Comment: @Dov I think the line of thinking follows Shmuel I 8 which implies the people wanted a King for more secular reasons and Hashem was being forsaken by the process. If you look at King Shaul, you'll see his leadership reflected this (focusing on establishing/securing the nation, leaving the Ark, ignoring Shmuel etc). Therefore it is not a surprise that his people spoke like that, and David's religious revival was hinted at in these pasukim. The case is too large to make in full, so I hope that's enough, otherwise feel free to just answer the same question about Shaul's men, and not Shaul himself

Comment: @Heshy in the pasuk, David accuses him of defying the armies of Hashem, which might map to your עמך. I notice this is to do with differences between nusach Sefard and Ashkenaz but I am unaware of any background to those differences. Could you help me understand your comment better?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any more info either, it was just the first thing I thought of seeing your question